# DataTrigger is evaluating just the first time

Tags: wpf

I have the following XAML code where I am trying to set the foreground of each row in a Toolkit DataGrid, based on a converter and a DataTrigger.

The converter examines the received object, which contains a collection of other objects, implementing the IDataErrorInfo interface. If the collection has items with errors, then the color is set to orange, otherwise to blue. If the collection does not contain non-empty items, the color is set to black.

Now, when I modify the collection from the UI, everything works well for the first time and the color is properly set. But then it seems that the DataTrigger is not evaluated anymore, because the converter does not stop in debug mode.

I cannot understand what I am missing.

My XAML:

```
<tk:DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle >
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type tk:DataGridRowHeader}}" TargetType="tk:DataGridRowHeader">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type tk:DataGridRow}}, Path=DataContext.Payload.TimeEventFunctions[0].IsEmpty}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type tk:DataGridRow}}, Path=DataContext.Payload, Converter={inf:DataGridRowHeaderForegroundConverter}}" />
            <!--<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DodgerBlue" />-->
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and the converter:

```
Public Class DataGridRowHeaderForegroundConverterExtension
Inherits Markup.MarkupExtension
Implements IValueConverter

Public Overrides Function ProvideValue(serviceProvider As System.IServiceProvider) As Object
    Return Me
End Function

Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
    Dim ret As New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
    If TypeOf value Is ISampleTableEntry Then
        Dim ste As ISampleTableEntry = DirectCast(value, ISampleTableEntry)
        Dim tevs As TrulyObservableCollection(Of ITimeEvFunc) = ste.TimeEventFunctions
        If tevs.Count > 0 AndAlso Not tevs(0).IsEmpty Then
            Dim query = From t In tevs Where t.HasErrors Select t
            If query IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim ErrorsPresent As Boolean = query.Count > 0
                ret = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 200, 0))
            Else
                ret = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.DodgerBlue)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return ret
End Function

Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Throw New NotSupportedException
End Function

End Class
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I forgotten to mention that if, in the XAML, I use commented setter, instead of the currently used, everything works well, so I suspect that it is something related to the use of the binding in the uncommented setter.

Comment: Try getting more info on the Binding by adding PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel. More info on that matter : http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52

Comment: Does you class implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes, it does. The problem is that the logic for obtaining the color involves the entire collection and not only one instance of the class.

Comment: You many not like this but what I would try is pass the collection to each object in the ctor so you can bind the Trigger to a property so the trigger will see the property changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is worth checking the "IsEmpty" property setter in the view model.. you must raise property changed event from that "IsEmpty" property setter..

And make sure to set default value to "Foreground" through setter. don't set the default value for foreground the the tag.

Comment: @Blam. It's more or less what I did: I defined in the view model a property HasErrors, referring to the collection, using also the property IsEmpty to get the value. Then using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface I routed the event to the view model.